# Error on search letters in a string with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm building a college project, a lexical analyzer.

I was able to assemble the whole structure, but my teacher asked that at the time of the search it is possible to click on the "space" to allow the search for other words.

My problem, if the word is the initial it searches without errors, the problem is that by clicking space and adding a new letter to search in my dictionary it does not change the position.

My code: https://codeshare.io/5QzkjQ

I guess my error is in: `else if ($i != intval(strlen($word)) - 1)`

Example: I get an input the $ _POST of the words: ball, car.

Now in my other input I first look for the word car, based on the position, car has 3 letters I give a space and it stays on the same line, now if I try to write the "b" ball it will keep on the last letter in case "r".

I do not know if I made myself very clear, but the code explains in a simpler way. Thank you!

Code:

```
<?php
$word = $_POST["word"];
$words = $_POST["words"];
$verifyProccess = $_POST["verifyProccess"];

$alfabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$linePosition = 1;
$maxLengMatrizTable = array(array(500), array(500));
$vecTable = array(500);
$initSizeMatrizTable = 0;

$symbols = explode(" ", $words);

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($symbols); $i++) {
    $trim = rtrim($symbols[$i], " ");
    $initSizeMatrizTable = $initSizeMatrizTable + strlen($trim);
}

$initSizeMatrizTable = $initSizeMatrizTable + 3;

for ($i = 1; $i < $initSizeMatrizTable; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < 27; $j++) {
        $maxLengMatrizTable[$i][$j] = "-";
    }
}

$lastLine = 1;
$totalLine = 1;
$nextLine = 1;
$cont = 0;

/* Adiciona a word na tabela passando as posicoes corretamente(monta a matriz já com as posições corretas) */
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($symbols); $i++) {
    $nextLine = 1;
    $trim = rtrim($symbols[$i], " ");

    for ($j = 0; $j < intval(strlen($trim)); $j++) {
        $alfabetPos = strripos($alfabet, $trim[$j]) + 1;

        if ($maxLengMatrizTable[$nextLine][$alfabetPos] == "-") {
            $lastLine = $lastLine + 1;
            $maxLengMatrizTable[$nextLine][$alfabetPos] = $lastLine;
            $totalLine = $totalLine + 1;
        }
        /* ultima posicao da palavra*/              
        $nextLine = $maxLengMatrizTable[$nextLine][$alfabetPos];

        if (intval(strlen($trim) - 1) == $j) {
            $vecTable[$cont] = $lastLine;
            $cont = $cont + 1;
        }
    }
}

$sizeMatriz = $totalLine + 1;
$errorPosition = $sizeMatriz - 1;

/* SEARCH! pegar da outra page */
/* faz a quebra da palavra */
for ($i = 0; $i < intval(strlen($word)); $i++) {
    $alfabetPos = strpos($alfabet, $word[$i]) + 1;

    if ($word[$i] != " ") {
        if ($alfabetPos != " " && $verifyProccess == true) {
            if ($maxLengMatrizTable[$linePosition][$alfabetPos] != "-" && $verifyProccess) {
                $verifyProccess = true;

                /* Define a proxima linha que ira pintar */
                $linePosition = $maxLengMatrizTable[$linePosition][$alfabetPos];

                $answer = array(
                    "linePosition"  =>  $linePosition,
                    "wordProccess"  =>  $verifyProccess
                );

            } else {
                $verifyProccess = false;

                $answer = array(
                    "linePosition" => $errorPosition,
                    "wordProccess" => $verifyProccess
                );
            }
        } else {
            $verifyProccess = false;

            $answer = array(
                "linePosition" => $errorPosition,
                "wordProccess" => $verifyProccess
            );
        }
    } else if ($i != intval(strlen($word)) - 1) {
        $final = false;

        for($j = 0; $j < sizeof($vecTable); $j++) {
            if($vecTable[$j] == $linePosition) {
                $final = true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        //
    }
}

$jsonanswer = json_encode($answer);
echo $jsonanswer;
```

Comment: Can you summarize what your script's goal is exactly/given what inputs?

Comment: In short, I give an input of words separated by space and capture with my $ _POST, after I search in my array of words the letter entered if it exists, if it exists, is valid if not invalid, in that I generate a table with the positions of the of the words where in my second input I type the letter and it will search the table, whether it exists or not.